# How can I make transparent appbar?

Tags: flutter

```
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Color(0xfff2edd7),
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Color(0x00000000),
    elevation: 0,
  ),
  drawer: _drawer(),
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: size.height * 0.3+100,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      //stops: [0.1, 0.6, 1],
                      colors: [Color(0xff4165a4), Color(0xff6573a4), Color(0xffa28aa5),Color(0xffccaaa7),Color(0xfff2edd7)])),
            ),
```

This is my part of code, and I want to make the color of appbar change by the color of container which have gradient color.

If I locate the body part higher than the appbar part, Will it be solved?

Comment: in your example, do you really need an appBar, they aren't required and if you want you could just put some text as a title in your Column

Comment: um I need appBar...But thank you for your idea! :)

Comment: ok, does @jitsm555 idea work? If not you might not have a choice and have to create your own appbar in your column. That is what I do for most of my projects as the UI gets more complex

Comment: Oh, can I make the appBar in a column?? I didn't know that! Thank you, and I'll try that soon! (I just decided to do other parts of my work first hehe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `backgroundColor` as transparent

```
  appBar: new AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0.0,
        ),
```

Comment: It just follow the color of Scaffold's backgroundcolor. maybe the problem is in that Scaffold's bgcolor. hmmmm how can I solve this problem...??

Comment: If AppBar is transparent then it will show scaffold bg color. that is intended behavior.

Comment: I just decided to do other parts first..hehe but thank you for your idea!